# Почему создается больше чем 1 HTPP запрос?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

подскажите пожалуйста. Пытаюсь потренироваться с сокетами.
При отправке запроса на 127.0.0.1:8000 в браузере программа несколько раз отрабатывает `server.accept`. Запрос отправляю один раз, но в консоле получаю, что создается несколько потоков, как будто `accept` срабатывет больше раз, чем один. Чего-то не понимаю в структуре работы или накосячил?
Я думал после срабатывания аксепта он должен ловить еще один запрос

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        try{
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                try{
                    new ServerThread(socket);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
```

ServerThread.java

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private Object in;
    private Object out;

    public ServerThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("rdy");
        socket = s;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Created instance of ServerThread");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Closed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ответ с консоли

```
rdy
Created instance of ServerThread
Closed
rdy
Created instance of ServerThread
Closed
rdy
Created instance of ServerThread
Closed
```

UPDATE Обнаружил, что второй запрос это favicon. Соответственно, мне нужно запрос проверять на него и фильтровать.

Comment: Каким образом отправляется запрос на указанный серверный сокет?

Comment: @AlexRudenko в браузере в адресной строке 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Тестируйте отправку более низкоуровневым инструментом типа nc (netcat). Протокол http разрешает браузеру повторно отправлять запрос, если на него не пришел ответ. Если откроете инструменты разработчика, то увидите, что если ваш сервер не отвечает вовремя как следует на http запросы, то браузер пробует заново.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Спасибо, действительно так. Попробовал телнетом. Отправляет один запрос успешно.
А подскажите как тогда бороться с браузером, если он пытается много раз отправить, по времени обращения отслеживать или как?

Comment: А зачем с этим бороться? Браузер же не просто так отправляет эти запросы. Если вы пишете веб-сервер или реализовываете протокол http вручную, то выхода нет - нужно реализовывать его или платить несовместимостью с какими-то браузерами. Может вам нужен совсем не http? Я не понимаю вашу задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ответ на соединение из браузера следует отправить какой-нибудь HTTP ответ, например, обычный `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n`:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
        System.out.println("Created instance of ServerThread");
        writer.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        // можно отправить какие-то HTTP заголовки
        writer.write("Content-Length: 0\r\n");
        System.out.println("Sent response");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```